# Send data to activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android

I have some activities: A, B, C, D ...
On each activity, it has buttons to start others. So:
    A can start B, C, D;
    B can start A, C, D;
    ...

I don't want to create multi instances of these activities, so I use flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT when start a activity.

Each time start a activity, I need pass data to it and update it's UI. But with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag, oncreate function is not called.

My question is: how to pass data between activities when use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag.

Comment: Great question +1, had the exact same requirements and managed to find your question really easily. Good job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be getting that request in A.`onNewIntent(Intent data)`, if the activity is not recreated. However, your logic needs to consider both cases: recreated and not. So you should have some setup method where you update the UI based on received intent.