# Send data to activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and taskAffinity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have almost the same requirements as this excellent question:

[Send data to activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943586/send-data-to-activity-with-flag-activity-reorder-to-front)

However, I'm using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` because each of my primary activities needs to run as a new task.  In my testing `onNewIntent` isn't called in this case (even when activity already running).  **So how do I pass data to it?**

I can get `onNewIntent` to be called, by setting `launchMode` to `singleTask`, however then I run in to this bug: [Android: bug in launchMode="singleTask"? -> activity stack not preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved)

I want to accomplish:

1. If no instance exists, create a new instance, as a new task, and pass it data.  (this part already works, I can get the data in onCreate)
2. If an instance already exists, bring the task (entire task, not just root/one activity) it is in to the front, and:
3. If task currently has a child activity displayed, do nothing
4. If task doesn't have a child activity displayed (just root/main activity), process the passed data and update the UI

I have one task with a button, "Go to Event", when clicked it needs to open/start the Calendar task and highlight a specific event (but the Calendar will ignore that request if another activity is being displayed over the top of it).

Comment: When I say "Calendar task" above, I'm referring to a task in my own application, not the built-in Calendar app or any other calendar app.

Comment: Can't you just pass in a bundle of extras with your intent?

Comment: That's what I do, and covers #1.  I can't figure out #2 (and 3 and 4) because onNewIntent isn't called, so how do I get the bundle if my activity is already running?

Comment: Have you tried the workarounds described in the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551195/intent-from-notification-does-not-have-extras)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @qbix's comment, I found this answer:

Add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP  -- which seems like it wouldn't be valid when combined with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, but it works.  It achieves all behaviors I listed above, and only fires onNewIntent if the activity is at the top of the stack, so I don't even have to worry about detecting that and ignoring.

More details here, even though this Q&A is related to PendingIntent and notifications:

[Intent from notification does not have extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551195/intent-from-notification-does-not-have-extras)